# How can I wait between generation 2 SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm programming a little game. I want to generate a random count of SKSpriteNodes on the screen but I want there is a few seconds wait between them.

Like: Node ... 3s... Node ... 1s.... Node... 2s...

I put them into

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        generateNode()
```

and then I wanted to put there sime `wait()` function or something like that... but I cant find anything. :( Anyone can help? Im doing it in swift. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`dispatch_after`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a sequence of `SKActions` and make your scene run it. You would have a custom action that adds a node. You can create a custom action that runs a block using:

```
class func runBlock(_ block: dispatch_block_t!) -> SKAction!
```

Then you add a delay using:

```
class func waitForDuration(_ sec: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction!
```

And you have to create a sequence of actions using:

```
class func sequence(_ actions: [AnyObject]!) -> SKAction!
```

Have look at [SKAction Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration:).

Comment: Hmm, dont understand how it should work. And also dont understand C-like notation... Is it like: add "waitForDuration" as a action to the node and it's all? I tried it like: var seq = SKAction.sequence([1action, 2action, SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1))])
but it doesnt work.

Comment: What is not working? And this is not C notation but Swift function prototypes copied from documentation.

Comment: there are still spawning Nodes as crazy. And I dont understand how should help to add "WaitForDuration" in node. They're all in separate thread. So whem one Node is waiting, another Node can by spawned.